# wp_list_pages() refuses to output posts

Tags: query, wp-list-pages, post-type

Someone help me understand why the following do not output anything:

```
wp_list_pages( 'post_type=post' )
wp_list_pages( 'post_type=event' )
```

Yet the following work as expected:

```
wp_list_pages( 'post_type=page' )
WP_Query( 'post_type=post' )
WP_Query( 'post_type=event' )
```

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_list_pages` will only output hierarchical post types. If we look at the function in source, we'll see that it calls `get_pages` to load pages for output. If we look at `get_pages` function in source, we'll see:

```
// Make sure the post type is hierarchical
$hierarchical_post_types = get_post_types( array( 'hierarchical' => true ) );
if ( !in_array( $post_type, $hierarchical_post_types ) )
    return false;
```

The default `post` post type is not hierarchical, so the function outputs nothing. If your `event` post type is also not hierarchical then that would explain why it also outputs nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It's a bummer there's no wp_list_posts() and wp_get_archives() does not include custom post types by default.